# Search Message extension oauth failing : value not found in enum type

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I implemented oauth in my search message extension. in local debug I see the sign in link and when clicking on it, it opens the window as well. But when I deploy the code to Azure, I dont even see the sign in link and it says unable to reach the app. Below are the error I saw on console:

[image]

Comment: Have you updated Azure bot resource message endpoint with App service domain? In the app service have you provided proper values of configuration?

Comment: If you are using sample, can you share?

Comment: Are there any updates on this?

Comment: Which App service Domain I have to register , could you please share a link with me which guides me for proper configuration? I am using this smaple: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsSearchAuthConfigBot.cs

Comment: So  you should have something like www.xyz.azurewebsties.net, this you need to put in Azure bot/ Bot channel registration -> Messaging endpoint - see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vesgO.png)  and make sure you have added Microsoft Teams in channel section - see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydyg4.png)

Comment: Yes, that is already done by the TeamsFx cli. I am using Teams Toolkit Preview and it does all these configuration.

Comment: Could you please share the bot Id and timestamp when you faced this issue.? I will look into logs. Also it would be lot helpful if you can check and share some logs.

Comment: Please find the contact details here - [Developer community](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) under General question section

Comment: I configured application insight and found the log for exception: BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR
 Error: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 8c8d86ab-5738-45d3-ba73-35cfa7581d01\r\nCorrelation ID: 74a8c58f-8748-4835-8b3d-ed35d34845f9\r\nTimestamp: 2021-10-08

Comment: and I am able to fix the issue as well.In Teams Toolkit, my app secret was overridden and hence invalid Client secret issue.

Comment: Yes, its usually about the configuration. Adding the comment as answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

**FIX**

Check the App Id and Secret given in Teams Toolkit. It should be correct. You can get more details in application insight.